# case in where clause - Toad SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

I am having an issue in the `where` clause of this `select`. Please let me know how to do it. For the  field `B.ACCOUNTING_DT` I have added `case` but it is throwing exception.

```
SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT,
PROJECT_ID,
INTEGRATION_TMPL,
NVL (SUM (CASE WHEN ANALYSIS_TYPE = 'ACT' THEN SUMMED_AMTS END), 0) - 
NVL (SUM (CASE WHEN ANALYSIS_TYPE = 'CLS' THEN SUMMED_AMTS END), 0) - 
NVL (SUM (CASE WHEN ANALYSIS_TYPE = 'EXP' THEN SUMMED_AMTS END), 0) PROJ_BAL,
NVL (SUM (CASE WHEN ANALYSIS_TYPE = 'ACT' THEN SUMMED_AMTS END), 0) ACTUAL,
NVL (SUM (CASE WHEN ANALYSIS_TYPE = 'CLS' THEN SUMMED_AMTS END), 0) CLOSE,
NVL (SUM (CASE WHEN ANALYSIS_TYPE = 'EXP' THEN SUMMED_AMTS END), 0) EXPENSE,
NVL (SUM (CASE WHEN ANALYSIS_TYPE = 'ACT' THEN SUMMED_AMTS END), 0) - 
NVL (SUM (CASE WHEN ANALYSIS_TYPE = 'CLS' THEN SUMMED_AMTS END), 0) - 
NVL (SUM (CASE WHEN ANALYSIS_TYPE = 'EXP' THEN SUMMED_AMTS END), 0) PROJ_BAL_END 
FROM
(SELECT A.BUSINESS_UNIT,
A.PROJECT_ID,
A.INTEGRATION_TMPL,
SUM(B.RESOURCE_AMOUNT)SUMMED_AMTS,
B.ANALYSIS_TYPE
FROM sysadm.PS_PROJECT A,
sysadm.PS_PROJ_RESOURCE B
WHERE A.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT
AND A.PROJECT_ID = B.PROJECT_ID
AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'PCCAP'
AND A.PROJECT_TYPE IN ('CAPTL','CSP','VEND' )
and B.ACCOUNTING_DT  = 
(CASE WHEN PROJ_BAL THEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT < '01-Oct-2013'),
(CASE WHEN ACTUAL  THEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT BETWEEN ('01-OCT-2013') AND ('31-OCT-2013')),
(CASE WHEN CLOSE   THEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT BETWEEN ('01-OCT-2013') AND ('31-OCT-2013')),
(CASE WHEN EXPENSE THEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT BETWEEN ('01-OCT-2013') AND ('31-OCT-2013')),
(CASE WHEN PROJ_BAL_END THEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT <= '31-Oct-2013') end case,
AND B.ACCOUNT IN ('1625',' ')
AND B.ANALYSIS_TYPE <> 'BUD'
GROUP BY A.BUSINESS_UNIT,
A.PROJECT_ID,
A.INTEGRATION_TMPL,
B.ANALYSIS_TYPE)
GROUP BY BUSINESS_uNIT,
PROJECT_ID,
INTEGRATION_TMPL;
```

Comment: what is the exception it's throwing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant this (Edited):

```
and B.ACCOUNTING_DT  = 
(CASE WHEN PROJ_BAL < '01-Oct-2013' THEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT
      WHEN ACTUAL BETWEEN ('01-OCT-2013') AND ('31-OCT-2013') THEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT
      WHEN CLOSE BETWEEN ('01-OCT-2013') AND ('31-OCT-2013') THEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT      
      WHEN EXPENSE BETWEEN ('01-OCT-2013') AND ('31-OCT-2013') THEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT
      WHEN PROJ_BAL_END <= '31-Oct-2013' THEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT END),
```

i.e.

```
`WHEN (Predicate) THEN COLUMN`
```

and not

```
`WHEN Column THEN COLUMN (Predicate)`
```

and the  `end case` needs to be fixed to just the one `END`

Comment: and B.ACCOUNTING_DT =
    (CASE WHEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT < '01-Oct-2013'THEN PROJ_BAL  ),
    (CASE WHEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT BETWEEN ('01-OCT-2013') AND 
    ('31-OCT-2013')THEN ACTUAL ),
    (CASE WHEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT BETWEEN ('01-OCT-2013') 
    AND ('31-OCT-  2013') THEN CLOSE   ),
    (CASE WHEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT BETWEEN ('01-OCT-2013') 
    AND ('31-OCT-2013') THEN EXPENSE  ),
    (CASE WHEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT <= '31-Oct-2013' THEN PROJ_BAL_END ) .

I changed like above but when i execute it says missing keyword, so am i missing end case??

Comment: Okay i changed like this
    and B.ACCOUNTING_DT =
    (CASE WHEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT < '01-Oct-2013'THEN PROJ_BAL End),
    (CASE WHEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT BETWEEN ('01-OCT-2013') AND ('31-OCT-  2013')THEN ACTUAL End),
    (CASE WHEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT BETWEEN ('01-OCT-2013') AND  ('31-OCT-2013') THEN CLOSE  End),
    (CASE WHEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT BETWEEN ('01-OCT-2013') AND ('31-OCT-2013') THEN EXPENSE  End),
    (CASE WHEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT <= '31-Oct-2013' THEN  PROJ_BAL_END End)
     AND B.ACCOUNT IN ('1625',' ')
     AND B.ANALYSIS_TYPE <> 'BUD'
But  i get ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error.

Comment: `B.ACCOUNTING_DT = (CASE WHEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT < '01-Oct-2013'THEN PROJ_BAL End), (CASE WHEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT BETWEEN ('01-OCT-2013') AND ('31-OCT- 2013')THEN ACTUAL End), (CASE WHEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT BETWEEN ('01-OCT-2013') AND ('31-OCT-2013') THEN CLOSE End), (CASE WHEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT BETWEEN ('01-OCT-2013') AND ('31-OCT-2013') THEN EXPENSE End), (CASE WHEN B.ACCOUNTING_DT <= '31-Oct-2013' THEN PROJ_BAL_END End) AND B.ACCOUNT IN ('1625',' ') AND B.ANALYSIS_TYPE <> 'BUD'`
But i get ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error.This is more readable i believe.

Comment: @Winona my apologies - the post was rather hasty. Have a look at the update?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using commas to separate your case statements, then maybe you intend to use the `IN()` operator, instead of `=`?

i.e.:

```
WHERE B.ACCOUNTING_DT IN(CASE WHEN...THEN...END, CASE WHEN...THEN...END,...)
```

Also -- I think with PLSQL (is that what you're targeting?) you don't use `'END CASE'`, but rather, just use `END`.  And all CASE statements (nested or otherwise) should have an `END`.

Also -- your predicates are in the `THEN` side, but should be in the `WHEN` side of the `CASE` instead.  i.e., somefield < some other field, etc.

Comment: Hi all, Thanks, Somehow i managed this query. But again i have issue in joining the 3 rd table to this query. If anyone can help i will post my query here.